# Laravel 5.1 - Can't access Auth:user()->data from my controllers

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I've been having a little trouble with Auth data in Laravel 5.1
I want to get the id of the Logged user and It works if I use it in a View, lets say:

```
<?php echo Auth::user()->id;?>
```

But if I try to access to it in a Controller it dowsnt work, and I get this error:

```
ErrorException in Con_Mascota.php line 101:
Trying to get property of non-object
```

In line 101 i've:

```
$cod_usu=$request->user()->cod_usu;
```

I changed that from $cod_usu=Auth::user()->cod_usu; cause that didnt work either.

Im also including it in the Controller:

```
use Auth;
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

I believe the problem is my Auth session is login out after refresh or after i go to another route:

My login funcions is:

```
    */
public function ini_ses(Request $datos)
{
    //Inicia sesion
  //  Session::put('ses_correo', Input::get('email'));

    $correo = $datos->input('email');
    $password= $datos->input('password');        

    if(Auth::attempt(['correo_elec'=>$correo, 'password'=>$password]))
    {
        $_session['correo']=$correo;
        $_session['contra']=$password;

        if(Auth::user()->tipo==0)
        {
            return view('cliente');
        }
        elseif(Auth::user()->tipo==1)
        {
            return view('veterinario');
        }
        elseif(Auth::user()->tipo==2)
        {
            echo("Admin");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var_dump($correo, $password);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class Usuario extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    public $timestamps = false;
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'usuario';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['cod_usu', 'correo_elec', 'nombre', 'ape_p', 'ape_m', 'telefono', 'celular', 'pais' , 'tipo'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['contra', 'remember_token'];
}
```

[image]

I found the solution, i changed this:

```
if(Auth::attempt(['correo_elec'=>$correo, 'password'=>$password]))
```

to this

```
if(Auth::attempt(['correo_elec'=>$correo, 'password'=>$password], true))
```

that eventyally made me have to change my cod_usu in the table for id, and reading jedrzej.kurylo's answer i guess that did the trick

Comment: Auth::user() returns the User object only if you're authenticated - otherwise it returns null and you're getting the error. Make sure you're authenticated or first check if you are by calling Auth::check() before Auth::user()->cod_usu

Comment: Auth::check() returns a false, but I'm accessing to that route right after I log in, I mean I log in, I get to my index view, then click to go to another route where I'm using Auth::check(), is there a reason I could be logging out automatically?

Comment: Did you implement login yourself or used AuthController that comes together with Laravel?

Comment: I used Laravels, I'll put my code in the post

Comment: Could you paste also your User model and users table schema?

Comment: Sure, I'll do it right now

Comment: Iam sure here  is the actual problem @user2639988  You are asking for session twice, Auth:: itself creates a session. $_session['correo']=$correo;
$_session['contra']=$password;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you log in, Laravel tries to save your user identifier in the session so that it can load it during subsequent requests. By default, model's ID field is called **id**, which is not true in your case. Therefore, after you authenticate, Laravel stores null as your user's ID and that's the reason it cannot load it later.

You need to tell Eloquent what is the name of your identifier column. You can do it by setting **$primaryKey** property of your **Usuario** class:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'cod_usu';
```

You'll need it not only to make your login work, but also to be able to define relations or make find method work for your models , e.g. **Usuario::find(123)** won't be able to load your user from the database.

Enabling **remember-me**, that helped in your case, worked by accident. By setting second parameter of **attempt()** to true you've enabled remember-me feature which results in creating a random identifier that is saved in **remember_toke** column in your table and later used to load your user data. It's not a proper way of handling your issue, it also will break your application if you decide to disable **remember-me** in the future.